# My arara typesetting code doesn't seem to be working

Tags: luatex, glossaries, glossaries-extra, arara

My arara code for LuaLaTeX typesetting doesn't seem to be working properly, as I need to typeset at least twice, and the glossaries are not being created:

> This document is incomplete. The external file associated with the
> glossary ‘MainGlossary’ (which should be called
> Differ2Latex-v29a9.myi) hasn’t been created.

Any thoughts on how/where the arara code may need to be updated/corrected would be appreciated. (The arara code was created some time ago, and may be out-of-date.)

```
% !TEX TS-program = Arara 
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% arara: lualatex: { synctex: on } 
% arara: lualatex: { synctex: on } 
% arara: bibtex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: makeglossaries if missing('gls') || changed('glo')
% arara: lualatex: { synctex: on } 
% arara: makeindex: { style: Differ2Latex-v29g9.ist }
% arara: makeindex: { style: Differ2Latex-v29g9.ist } if changed ('idx') || missing ('ind')
% arara: nomencl 
% arara: makeglossaries if found('aux', '@istfilename')
% arara: lualatex: { synctex: on } 
% arara: makeindex: { style: Differ2Latex-v29g9.ist } if changed ('idx') || missing ('ind')
% arara: lualatex: { synctex: on } 
% arara: authorindex
% arara: lualatex: { synctex: on }
```

Also, if there is any way to confirm that the arara code is actually executed, such a feature would be helpful.

Thanks again.

Comment: Whether the `arara`-code you have given here will work or not completely depends on what you have in your TeX code. E.g., your third directive will fail if you don't have bibliography related commands in the source file. Copy pasting the same `arara`-code (that too such a specific one) is not going to help you at all.

Comment: If you want to see whether your `arara` is working or not, the simplest way is to run `arara` through a terminal. You need to specify your OS.

Comment: Are you running `arara` on the same file with same style files (i.e., Differ2Latex-v29g9.ist) or on a different one?

Comment: @Niranjan - Thank you. Re: You need to specify your OS. - `MacOS`. Re: your third directive will fail if you don't have bibliography related commands in the source file. `All the necessary bibliography related commands are there.` Re: the simplest way is to run arara through a terminal - `Let me give that a try - Thank you!`

Comment: My question remains ... is there a mechanism within arara (outside of running within terminal) for feedback at each step of the arara process. I haven't seen anything in the typesetting .log file to indicate such progress, but then again, I'm not sure I would know what to look for within the .log file. Thanks for reading!

Comment: `arara` has a `--verbose` mode. The log file that you see still shows the log of LaTeX-run. It cannot carry the information generated by `arara`. To see what is happening on each step of `arara`, simply run `arara --verbose filename`. On GNU Linux I can also command `arara --verbose filename > araralog` which generates a file called `araralog` and saves all the information generated by that `arara`-run.

Comment: I don't know which editor you are using, but in customizable editors like GNU Emacs or TeXStudio, you can edit the default method of using `arara` and add the `--verbose` flag by default so that you see the full log always.

Comment: @Niranjan - Thank you for your updates ... I've been perusing the arara 4.0 `arara-manual.pdf` as well as the example in `Dickimaw Books` (https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/html/arara.shtml) et al. for some insight. I will try the `arara --verbose <filename>` option. I am using the TeXShop typesetter ... I will check to see if I can add the `--verbose` flag as a default. Thank you for the suggestions. What is a little surprising is what appears to be a dearth of examples of the arara directives, given how powerful if can be when typesetting large, complicated projects. Thanks again!

Comment: @Niranjan - Correction ... that s/b arara version 7.1.0, not 4.0!

Comment: `arara` is indeed very powerful! I am glad that you are following proper documentation. One advice is lesser specific `arara`-setup is to a particular file, more productive it becomes. You will eventually get to know about all these things in the documentation itself.

Comment: @Niranjan - I generally look for code examples as a way to learn ... the documentation is a bit sparse on full blown examples of arara directives ... searching now for examples elsewhere ... Thanks for all your assistance!

Comment: In contrast to what @Niranjan said: The offiicial way to get a log file with all details (and a few more of the verbose run) is to run arara with the `-l` flag to generate a log file (`arara.log`). This log file contains more than `arara --verbose filename > araralog` and is thus recommended, also for debugging.

Comment: @TeXnician thanks for this information. I wasn't aware of it, but I don't think it is in contrast to what I said. It definitely provides a better alternative, but saying that it is in contrast either means that I had denied the possibility of better alternatives or I had suggested that method as the "official" one. I had done neither of these. So kindly use softer words and thanks again for correcting me. :-)

Comment: @Niranjan Sorry, but I stay with my “in contrast to” because you said about the redirect “generates a file called araralog and saves *all* the information generated by that arara-*run*”, which is inaccurate at best and misleading at worst. You will not get all information generated by the arara run (in contrast to enabling logging). With your redirect you only get the commands' output as well as the directive names arara outputs. Anyway, I think comments here (which always ping OP) should not discuss my wording but the matter at hand (feel free to ping me in chat about my word choice, though).